# Как загрузить картинку в базу данных?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql

Как на c# загрузить картинку в базу данных? В базе есть поле типа image, и необходимо "засунуть туда фото" из жесткого диска, пользователь указывает путь к файлу и он отправляется в базу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Всегда отправлял в базу только путь к файлу, намного проще.

Comment: как? а где хранить сами фото?
ну....а если хранить ссылку в базе, то как тогда на основании этой ссылки загрузить фото из сервера....и как загрузить на сервер, вписав эту ссылку...

Comment: Если уж все-таки охота хранить файлы в бд тогда можно использовать новый функционал FileTable в MS SQL Server 2012, который поддерживает полную синхронизацию файловой системы и базы данных. Это так, к слову :)

Comment: А на сколько это в принципе оправдано хранить изображения в БД вместо файловой системы, ну не считая удобства работы с данными?

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтобы загрузить картинку в базу данных, мы разбиваем его на массив байтов и заливаем в столбец таблицы в Базе Данных типа: varbinary(max) или image.
Пример кода:

```
               // Добавить ФОТОГРАФИЮ в Базу Данных
                
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapImage)Picture.Source));
                encoder.Save(stream);
                book.Picture = stream.ToArray();
```

Покажу полный пример кода, где происходит добавление данных о книгах в базу данных.
WPF C#, MS SQL Server:

```
 private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.Name = NameBookTextBox.Text;
                var currentGenre = DbContextObj.db.Genre.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == ComboBoxGenre.Text);
                book.IDGenre = currentGenre.ID;
                book.CountPage = int.Parse(CountPageBookTextBox.Text);
                var currentAutrhor = DbContextObj.db.Author.FirstOrDefault(item => item.FirstName == AuthorFirstNameComboBox.Text);
                book.IDAuthor = currentAutrhor.ID;
                book.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceTextBox.Text);
                var currentPublisher = DbContextObj.db.Publisher.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == PublisherBookComboBox.Text);
                book.IDPublisher = currentPublisher.ID;
                // Добавить ФОТОГРАФИЮ в Базу Данных
                {
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapImage)Picture.Source));
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                    book.Picture = stream.ToArray();
                }
                DbContextObj.db.Book.Add(book);
                DbContextObj.db.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Сохранено!");
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Для того чтобы подключить MemoryStream , напишите в директориях using Microsoft.Win32, а для JpegBitmapEncoder  используем: 
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging.

Comment: Грязновато пишете. Если используете потоки, то надо использовать `using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())` или закрывать поток вручную, а не бросать поток на волю Аллаха как у вас сейчас сделано.

Comment: @Bulson MemoryStream не держит никаких неуправляемых ресурсов, поэтому using тут не нужен

Answer (score 2):

[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre) совершенно верно говорит, гораздо проще и удобнее хранить в базе путь к изображению, а само изображение либо в файловой системе либо в CDN. То есть вместо потока байтов делаете текстовое поле, которое хранит путь к файлу. Во время работы файл кладете (или читаете) куда-то в файловую систему, а в таблице - путь к нему.

Картинку читаете из файла стандартно - вызовом [Image.FromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/stf701f5.aspx) или как-то еще.

Comment: Я немного не понял....судя по ссылке...
пользователь №1 подключается и записывает фото сотрудника со своего винта в базу...
пользователь №2 проверяет ссылку и по ссылке,которая соответстует расположению файла на сервере, выдаёт поток данного файла и пользователь №2 видит фото.

Comment: И не очень понятно, где всётаки будут храниться фото?
необходимо тогда на винчестере сервера, а в базе ссылку держать.
а какая "система" это всё будет реализовать, когда я решил добавить фото, оно ж должно отправиться на сервер в файловую систему, а в базе записаться ссылка к файлу...и обратный процесс...
можете пожалуйста кинуть ссылку где подобное делается?
или я бред гоню...а всё делается не так?

Answer (score 2):

Посоветовал бы вам освежить в памяти  [вот это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k3352a4t.aspx)

Для начала решите для себя вопрос о том что же хранить в БД - ссылку на файл или же непосредственно сам файл. (из собственного опыта скажу что оба варианта имеют право на жизнь при определенных внешних условиях).

Если же решением будет хранение файлов в самой бд, то для этого вам необходимо:

1. Читаем массив байт byte[] из файла (как раз верхняя ссылка пригодится если возникнут проблемы)
2. Пишем полученный массив в нужное CLOB поле таблицы БД. Как именно это делается - зависит от вашего инструментария и привычки.

Загрузка изображения из БД происходит аналогично : из CLOB в byte[] и далее в зависимости от ваших нужд (сохранение в качестве файла или же отрисовка)